# Exposing collection of arguments for activity in Property Grid

Tags: visual-studio-2010, workflow-foundation-4, designer, propertygrid

`ExecuteSqlQuery` activity from [WF ADO.NET Activity Pack CTP 1](http://wf.codeplex.com/releases/view/43585) has a nice dialog for its `Parameters` property. I would like to use the same approach for my custom activity to provide user with ability to specifying any number of arguments in design mode and binding each argument to an expression. Is there a way to use this existing dialog box?

[image: Collection Property Designer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DynamicActivityDialog` provides this functionality:

```
ModelItem modelItem = this.ModelItem.Properties["Arguments"].Dictionary;
using (ModelEditingScope change = modelItem.BeginEdit("ArgumentsEditing"))
{
    if (DynamicArgumentDialog.ShowDialog(this.ModelItem, modelItem, Context, this.ModelItem.View, options))
    {
        change.Complete();
    }
    else
    {
        change.Revert();
    }
}
```

And in the activity, you must have the initialized property:

```
public Dictionary<string, Argument> Arguments {get; private set;}
```

You can populate the `Dictionary<string, Argument>` before show the dialog for predefined itens.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I have been looking for. I also found the answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6912935/940906